# Statement completion in Windows Terminal displays but doesn't engage

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, terminal, windows-terminal

Recently Windows Terminal got updated and it got History suggestions. It looks like this:

[image]

As I type, it shows the history item that matches my entry. I thought pressing Tab would auto complete the portion in gray, but it doesn't. I tried various other hotkeys, but they do nothing either. I looked in Windows Terminal settings, but couldn't find anything relevant.

What can I do to enable completion of the text?

P.S. I am not 100% sure if this is a Windows Terminal feature. I suppose it could be Powershell or PSReadLine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like [Az Predictor](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.Tools.Predictor/) module is installed with your powershell. If that is the case, you need to press <kbd>→</kbd> (right arrow key) to complete the cmdlet(s).

To check if Az Predictor is installed, run the following cmdlet:

```ps
Get-module -Name "Az.Tools.Predictor"
```

Comment: I don't have this module [installed](https://i.imgur.com/G03kIfv.png).   But the shortcut key you suggested worked!!!  Problem solved!